# How to avoid using exit when redirecting from Observer

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.4, registration

I have an observer that is triggered when a user creates an account. In the `execute` method I have the following code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('subscribe');
    $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

It does infact redirect as expected, but the user is not logged in after registration.

How can I redirect without having to use `exit`? If I remove `exit` the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: Instead of `exit` just use `return $this`.

Comment: Doing so causes the redirect to fail, and instead the user is redirected to their account page. This is not what I want.

Comment: What is the event you are attaching this observer to?

Comment: `customer_register_success`